# Strange behaviour in a function while implementing the alpha-beta pruning algorithm

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chess

I've implemented a minimax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning. In order to get the best move, I call the alpha-beta algorithm with the `rootAlphaBeta` function. However, in the `rootAlphaBeta` function, I spotted some very strange behaviour. When I call the `rootAlphaBeta` function with a `ply` of 4, it makes about 20 000 calls, but when I call the `alphaBeta` function directly, it makes only about 2000 calls. I can't seem to find what's the problem, as the number of calls should be the same.

The move that both algorithms eventually find should be the same, right? I think so, at least the score of the move is the same, I have no way of knowing the move the `alphaBeta` chooses when I call it directly without `rootAlphaBeta`.

```
def alphaBeta(self, board, rules, alpha, beta, ply, player):
    """Implements a minimax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning."""
    if ply == 0:
        return self.positionEvaluation(board, rules, player)

    move_list = board.generateMoves(rules, player)
    for move in move_list:
        board.makeMove(move, player)
        current_eval = -self.alphaBeta(board, rules, -beta, -alpha, ply - 1,
                                       board.getOtherPlayer(player))
        board.unmakeMove(move, player)

        if current_eval >= beta:
            return beta

        if current_eval > alpha:
            alpha = current_eval

    return alpha


def rootAlphaBeta(self, board, rules, ply, player):
    """Makes a call to the alphaBeta function. Returns the optimal move for a 
    player at given ply."""
    best_move = None
    max_eval = float('-infinity')

    move_list = board.generateMoves(rules, player)
    for move in move_list:
        board.makeMove(move, player)
        current_eval = -self.alphaBeta(board, rules, float('-infinity'),
                                       float('infinity'), ply - 1,
                                       board.getOtherPlayer(player))
        board.unmakeMove(move, player)

        if current_eval > max_eval:
            max_eval = current_eval
            best_move = move

    return best_move
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `rootAlphaBeta` doesn't update the `alpha` value. It calls all its child nodes with the full range of (-inf, inf), when it could have narrowed down the range for all child nodes except the first. This will prevent pruning of some branches which will have no effect on the final score, and increase the node count.