# How is the alpha value in alpha-beta pruning algorithm used and updated?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, alpha-beta-pruning

I was looking at the post [Strange behaviour in a function while implementing the alpha-beta pruning algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12569392/3924118) and the accepted answer, where it is stated: "Your `rootAlphaBeta` doesn't update the alpha value". I was wondering what the necessary addition to the code was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For alpha-beta pruning to work, the alpha value needs to get propagated up to the top level of the depth first search. This can be achieved by initializing a variable to store alpha outside of the loop over the potential moves, storing the result of the call to `alphaBeta()` in it, and then using it as an argument to `alphaBeta()`. In code that will look like:

```
def rootAlphaBeta(self, board, rules, ply, player):
    """ Makes a call to the alphaBeta function. Returns the optimal move for a player at given ply. """
    best_move = None
    max_eval = float('-infinity')

    move_list = board.generateMoves(rules, player)
    alpha = float('infinity')
    for move in move_list:
        board.makeMove(move, player)
        alpha = -self.alphaBeta(board, rules, float('-infinity'), alpha, ply - 1, board.getOtherPlayer(player))
        board.unmakeMove(move, player)

        if alpha > max_eval:
            max_eval = alpha
            best_move = move

    return best_move
```

Comment: Isn't there some typo in your code? It looks like you are updating the beta value and not the alpha.

Comment: Do you mean that I'm updating beta but not alpha? Because I'm updating alpha on the second line of the for loop. I believe all of the updating of beta happens in the alphaBeta() function in the original question (here I'm just writing the rootAlphaBeta() function, since that's where the problem was).

Disclaimer: I wrote this 5 years ago and haven't used alpha-beta pruning much since, so it's entirely possible I made a mistake.